# convert "Nested ArrayList XML" to java Object using Two Custom Converters of XStream

Tags: java, xml, arraylist, xml-parsing, xstream

Above XML has nested ArrayList Structure

I have written a code as

```
{   XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.processAnnotations(Travels.class);

    String xml = xstream.toXML(t);
    System.out.println(xml);

    xstream.registerConverter(new HolidaysConverter());
    xstream.registerConverter(new FlightConverter());

    xml = xstream.toXML(t);


    Travels t1=(Travels)xstream.fromXML(xml);

}
```

XML is

```
<Travels> 
  <Holidays> 
    <duration>10</duration>
    <Flight>
       <fid>255A</fid>
    </Flight>
  </Holidays>
  <Holidays>
    <duration>20</duration>
    <Flight>
      <fid>100B</fid>
   </Flight>
 </Holidays>
</Travels>
```

This code giving an error given below

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: null : null
>   ---- Debugging information ---- cause-exception : java.lang.RuntimeException cause-message : null class : Flight
>   required-type : Flight converter-type : FlightConverter path :
>   /Travels/Holidays/Flight line number : 4 class[1] : Holidays
>   converter-type[1] :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
>   class[2] : Travels version : null

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: null : null
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.RuntimeException
cause-message       : null
class               : Flight
required-type       : Flight
converter-type      : FlightConverter
path                : /Travels/Holidays/Flight
line number         : 4
class[1]            : Holidays
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : Travels
version             : null

Comment: There is no "Above XML" and also no "error given below" in your post.  This makes it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: No, please add your XML and error message to your post using the EDIT facility.

Comment: XML Structure<Travels>
  <Holidays>
    <duration>10</duration>
    <Flight>
      <fid>255A</fid>
    </Flight>
  </Holidays>
  <Holidays>
    <duration>20</duration>
    <Flight>
      <fid>100B</fid>
    </Flight>
  </Holidays>
</Travels>

Comment: @SushobhitDua .. edit your question and put information there .. so that all information can seen at a glance